# Elasticsearch hardware recommendations

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm deploying an Elasticsearch cluster with roughly 20MB a day with a time-to-live of 180 days. What would be the best hardware requirements for this amount of data? How many master and data nodes may require in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: That boils down to <4GB of data. A single 8GB node should be sufficient to hold and search the data. Now, this is to be taken with a grain of salt, as it will of course depend on your use case(s) and how you need to leverage the data, but storage-wise, one node is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

20MB every day with retention period of 6 months is very less amount of  data, you can have one node(which can also have master role) to serve your use case, CPU and memory size you can adjust according to your search and index traffic and can easily be done if you using cloud to create the nodes(AWS etc)

Just remember to give 50% of your RAM as Elasticsearch heap size to get optimal performance.